# Finding pattern- $6$ $11$ $25$

Tags: pattern-recognition

> Finding pattern$$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         6 & 11 & (25) \\
>         8 & 6 & (16) \\
>         12 & 5 & (?) \\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$ Options are : $10/12/14/16$

My attempt: $11-6=5, 5^2=25$. But it's not valid for next. $6^2-11=25$, but not valid for next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use $$6x+11y=25\ \ \  \ (1)$$

$$8x+6y=16\ \ \ \  (2)$$

and $$12x+5y=c$$

Solve  $(1),(2)$ for $x,y$

Answer (score 4):

An idea.

I guess the answer is $16$.

For $$a\ \ \ b\ \ \ (c),$$
the following holds :

$$(a/2)+2b=c.$$